# Rename and move files in batch-dos

Tags: batch-file, dos, file-rename

I want to rename files and transfer them into a library using a batch file in the following way:

```
c:\jg_Folder_xy>
blabla01_000.bla --> blabla01_001.bla
blabla02_000.bla --> blabla02_001.bla
blabla03_000.bla --> blabla03_001.bla

c:\sj_Folder_mx>
blabla01_000.bla --> blabla01_002.bla
blabla02_000.bla --> blabla02_002.bla
blabla03_000.bla --> blabla03_002.bla

c:\an_Folder_kj>
blabla01_000.bla --> blabla01_003.bla
blabla02_000.bla --> blabla02_003.bla
blabla03_000.bla --> blabla03_003.bla
```

and than transfer all into a new folder

```
c:\New_Folder>
blabla01_001.bla
blabla01_002.bla
blabla01_003.bla
blabla02_001.bla
blabla02_002.bla
blabla02_003.bla
blabla03_001.bla
blabla03_002.bla
blabla03_003.bla
```

anyone knows what is the most efficient way?

NOTE: folders name have only one sub string in common

Answer (score 3):

### How to do it

Here's a simple solution in batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "SRC_PATH=c:\jg_Folder_xy"
set "DEST_PATH=c:\New_Folder"
for %%f in ("%SRC_PATH%"\*.bla) do (
    set fname=%%~nf
    set fbase=!fname:~0,-4!
    set findex=!fbase:~-2!
    move %%f "%DEST_PATH%"\!fbase!_0!findex!%%~xf
)
```

**Note:** this script has to be run on each source folder separately (changing `SRC_PATH` each time). Alternatively, you can modify the `for` loop to a double loop, like so:

```
for /d %%d in (*_Folder_*) do for %%f in ("%%d"\*.bla) do (
```

so that it'll iterate automatically over all files in all desired folders (the `SRC_PATH` line won't be needed).

### How it works

The `for` loop iterates over the files in the source folder, and assigns the filename (with the full path) to `%%f` in each iteration.

`set fname=%%~nf` extracts the filename and drops the extension.

`set fbase=!fname:~0,-4!` obtains all but the last 4 characters (*i.e.* drops the "_000").
This essentially extracts the base filename, which is "blabla01", "blabla02"... in your example.

`set findex=!fbase:~-2!` extracts the last 2 characters from the `fbase`, i.e. the running index.
It is assumed that the running index is exactly two characters.

The `move` command renames the files and moves them into the destination folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: although it helped me alot, It produces a lot of errors, and still have not figured it out

Comment: Well that's odd. I wouldn't post something that doesn't work for me... so allow me to work it out for you. Did you use the `for /d %%d` loop or the `for %%f` loop? What errors did you get?