# Batch file Script to Rename a portion of file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, automation

I need to rename the below file from:

`15113810_MOM-20024-20130601_015840-1.jar`

To

`MOM-20024-20130601_015840-2.jar`

`15113810(this is a variable)_MOM-20024-20130601_015840-1.jar`

How can I do this with a script?

```
echo off 
if not exist "C:\BODimp\28007\incoming" /M *.txt /D +0 goto BODIMP goto
c:\batch\stopmnctl.bat && c:\batch\startopmnctl.bat
:END

:BODIMP
IF not EXIST "C:\BODimp\28007\archive" /M *.txt /D +0 goto execute goto
forfiles /P "C:\BODimp\archive" /M *.txt /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path C:\BODimp"
:END

:EXECUTE
forfiles /P "C:\BODimp\28007\archive" /M *.txt /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path C:\BODimp\28007"
:END
```

Please include this renaming logic in this.

My requirement here is to copy the jar file of above format from a specific folder & to rename it by removing the numerical rite side of first '_' & put 2 in place of 1 or 3 if it is 2 ..(i.e x+1 incremental order) & move it to another folder where that file will get consumed to Dbase.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet or are you wanting us to write it for you?

Comment: Are you really changing it from 1.jar to 2.jar or is that a typo?  What are the rules for that numeral if it is intentional?  Question 2: are you changing one file or a number of files in a single folder?

Comment: hi howlin Philip & foxidrive.. My requirement here is to copy the jar file of above format from a specific folder & to rename it by removing the numericals rite side of first '_' & put 2 in place of 1 or 3 if it is 2 ..(i.e x+1 incremental order) & move it to another folder where that file will get consumed to Dbase.

Answer (score 0):

Go to that folder by using `cd`, then

```
move 15113810_MOM-20024-20130601_015840-1.jar MOM-20024-20130601_015840-2.jar
```

---

**Edit:** Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049845/2589776) if you want to rename and move files in batch-dos.

Comment: hi this is not for a single file .. We have nearly 800 stores where dialy new files with the above format will reside. I want to rename them automatically..

Comment: like splitting the name based on '_' or something like that.. please check & update on the possibility

Comment: thanks for the update.. working on that will cum back with the update

Answer (score 0):

try this method to work out the new name.

```
@echo off
set source_filename=15113810_MOM-20024-20130601_015840-1.jar
echo.source_name=%source_filename%

for /F "usebackq tokens=2-7 delims=-_." %%i in ('%source_filename%') do call :rename_sub %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n

goto :EOF

REM routine to do the rename
:rename_sub
set prefix=%1
set number=%2
set filedate=%3
set filetime=%4
set count=%5
set extension=%6

set /a "count+=1"
set target_name=%prefix%-%number%-%filedate%_%filetime%-%count%.%extension%

echo.target_name=%target_name%

goto :EOF
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot.. here we wont be knowing the source file name,we can just specify the path of file & we need to copy the latest file & rename it & then need to paste in other folder

Comment: yes, the example is just for the renaming bit you where asking about. You will need to find the name of the latest file using the script you published in your question then rename it, then copy it to new folder with the new name. Best put something together then repost with your complete script and any further questions

Comment: What is not working? what have you tried? please post the complete script you have produced and are trying from the help given so far and description of what is failing and any error messages on the command line. Might be able to help further then. (try running without the echo off commadns to see what is going on)

Comment: hey thanks a lot.. its done now. actually did in vbs..thanks a lot for your inputs..